# working with sqlite3 in mac os x 10.9

Tags: sql, macos, sqlite

I know that Mac OSx has pre-installed sqlite3.But when I am entering this command, when in
/usr/bin directory, sqlite3 test.db i get this displayed on terminal..

```
Adityas-MacBook-Air:bin adityabahuguna$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
```

Its fine till now. But when i try to create a table by

```
sqlite> create table t(name text);
```

I always get this error:

```
Error: unable to open database "test.db": unable to open database file
```

This however does not occur when i directly use create table command without creating a new database. I want to figure out the way to create a new database (say test.db as above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create the database in `/usr/bin` where normal users don't have write access.

You can write to `/usr/bin` with root/sudo as suggested by Atul but that's not really something you should do.

Instead, specify a database path that is writable by your normal user, for example

```
sqlite3 ~/test.db
```

so the `test.db` gets created in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be logged in as root user to have create database privilege. you can become root user by following these steps: [How to Become root user.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528)

Comment: i found the easier way. instead of logging in as root we can run the command "sudo sqlite3 new_database.db" (quotes for clarity), at the terminal when logged in as admin. when database is created type the usual CREATE TABLE...etc commands...we r good to go